# How to embed flv video for IE8

Tags: html, video, internet-explorer-8, flv

I'm trying to embed a flv video for IE8. 
This is my code:

```
<video width="265" height="150" controls poster="img/anteprima_pomodorino.jpg">
            <source src="img/Pomodorino.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
            <embed id="flash_fallback" class="vjs-flash-fallback" width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" flashvars="&amp;file=img/Pomodorino.flv&amp;image=img/anteprima_pomodorino.jpg&amp;height=280&amp;width=440&amp;lightcolor=0xEFEFEF&amp;frontcolor=0xEFEFEF&amp;backcolor=0x666666&amp;autostart=false" allowfullscreen="true" src="swf/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf"></embed> 
</video>
```

I'm not able to make it work, the video doesn't play on IE8. Where is the mistake? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

IE8 doesn't support HTML5 video. You can try something like VideoJS, MediaElement.js or JW Player which has a Flash fallback.